# Discord bot TypeError. Can't connect it to my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, eris

I am trying to make a Discord bot that sends a specific message ("!clean") to a specified text channel on Discord every 30 minutes or something like that. I've run into a bunch of problems, and this is the furthest I've gotten.
I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

This is what happens when I try to start the bot:
[image]

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z76op.png)

*No, I did not write any of the code myself... This is my first time ever using JS. I copied someone else's code and combined it.*

- I use Node 14.4.0

Edit: All I want to do is to make a simple bot that sends a message to a specific text channel, the message being "!clean" every 30 minutes. My attempts have all failed miserably.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I removed the image of your code because it contained your bot's token. Please re-edit your code back in when you've regenerated the token.

Comment: first: what is eris, second: you left your token exposed in your screenshot (edit: not anymore), meaning everyone can access your bot, third: if you are using discord.js >= v12, bot.channels.find does not work anymore, fourth: you have multiple bot.on(ready)'s, fifth: on line 49 in setInterval, it says it sends every 5 seconds, even though the interval is 10 seconds, sixth: you are console.warn()ing errors

Comment: To add on to what @Diggy. said, be extremely cautious with your bot token. If the first person to find this was someone else, they could easily take over your bot and cause it to do all sorts of things you don't want it to. As you may recall, when generating a bot token on the Discord Developer page, it reminds you to be careful with it. Now that you know that, good luck!



EDIT: I would strongly recommend regenerating your token, as anyone can view past edits which includes your screenshot with your token. If you aren't sure how to do that, I (and probably others) will be happy to help.

Comment: Also important to note: if the message that you are trying to send, "!clean," is meant to trigger another bot, it is likely that this will not work. Most mainstream bots do not respond to other bots, as a safety measure and to prevent infinite message loops or spam. EDIT: for an example, imagine two bots. One has a command `.say` and the other has `!say`. Both commands say the words after. If a user were to run `.say !say .say !say .say !say .say !say hello`, then there would be eight bot messages. If a user wrote that message to the 2000 character limit, it could spam the server for ages.

Comment: Reset your token, you just leaked it

Comment: @Diggy., I regenerated my token after uploading the photo.

Comment: Alos @Syntle and other people

Answer (score 0):

Tad late, but when working with Eris, you cannot that easily access every channel from the Client. You can instead use [`Client.getChannel(<ChannelID>)`](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/Client#function-getChannel). If you must filter all channels, you can use `Client.channelGuildMap` which returns an Object of Guild IDs and their Channel IDs.

If the Channel ID changes based on what the user gives, make sure to check if the Channel allows sending messages!

(Be sure to replace `Client` with whatever your bot variable is :>)

EDIT: Keep in mind this as well: Bots ignore other bot accounts usually by design. To be on the safe side, you would have to make your own message purge command yourself. If this bot is running on a User account and not a bot account, I'd [advise against that](https://discord.com/developers/docs/legal#2-license-accounts-and-restrictions) as you could be banned from Discord entirely.